C++ memory order / acquire-release semantics - please confirm if I understand this correctly
Consider the following piece of code:
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

std::atomic<int> data(0);
std::atomic<int> data2(0);
std::atomic<bool> ready(false);

void producer()
{
    data.store(42, std::memory_order_relaxed); // (1) this instruction is guaranteed to execute before ready.store
    ready.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
    data2.store(28, std::memory_order_relaxed); // (2) the compiler could decide to execute this instruction before ready.store
}

void consumer()
{
    int value2 = data2.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // (3) the compiler could decide to execute this instruction after ready.load
    while (!ready.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
    {

    }
    int value = data.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // (4) this instruction is guaranteed to execute after ready.load
    std::cout << "Consumed value: " << value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Consumed value 2: " << value2 << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    std::thread t1(producer);
    std::thread t2(consumer);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}

My question: Are the statements (1 through 4) that I put in the comments correct?
Note: This is how I understood it from existing topics on the subject (like this one: Understanding `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_release` in C++11). But now the AI says that statement 2 is incorrect, and I am not completely trusting it....

(1) yes, (2) yes, (3) yes, (4) yes

one reason a CPU will execute data2.store before ready.store is so it will optimize its cache writes, where both data1 and data2 are on the same cache line so it will flush it once instead of twice. AI is a smart autocorrect, it has no concept of C++ or computers

It seems roughly correct to me. Though, it is more accurate to discuss it in terms of visibility. Say, hypothetically, the load in (4) may be executed before acquire but the result must satisfy the release-acquire memory ordering (which is probably not feasible if the load is executed before the acquire fence). So value should always be 42.

@ALX23z you mention that "the load in (4) may be executed before acquire". Could you explain this further? Doesn't that violate the statement that "no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before this load" (according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

@FantaBlack28: Because of out-of-order execution, the times at which the instructions are executed does not necessarily correspond to the order in which they read from memory.  That's why we don't generally use the word "executed" in this context.

@FantaBlack28: I think "reordering" is likewise a risky concept, as it implies they had an ordering to begin with, which was then changed to a new ordering.  Some effects allowed by the C++ memory model aren't consistent with any ordering. Hence "visibility" as preferred; we ask which instructions are able to be observed by which others.

The C++ standard itself isn't written in terms of "reordering".  The authors / contributors of cppreference chose to write in those terms, perhaps because it's easier to understand, but it can introduce subtle inaccuracies.  Remember cppreference is an unofficial source; it's generally very very good, but it's not perfect, and there can be places where their explanations are inaccurate or misleading.

Compile-time reordering of (3) seems unlikely; a good compiler shouldn't move it past a potentially-infinite loop.  And moving it into a loop isn't something a real compiler would do.  On x86-64, compile-time reordering is the only mechanism for memory order not to match program order for this code (since you don't have any reloads of your own stores (store-forwarding), or any non-seq_cst stores before non-seq_cst loads).  But most other ISAs allow reordering at runtime. https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/ + https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/

@PeterCordes: It seems plausible to me. If there were a lot of code inside the loop imposing register pressure, then pushing the load past the loop could avoid a spill. Maybe I'll play with it sometime.

@NateEldredge Well I guess in this case the result isn't used before the loop, but it could still violate the "should be visible in reasonable time" requirement. https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0062r1.html mentions a progress-bar case for when it's bad to move atomics wrt. a long-running loop.  How C++ Standard prevents deadlock in spinlock mutex with memory_order_acquire and memory_order_release? is another case where compilers need to avoid moving atomic ops wrt. potentially-infinite loops, so I expect compilers are reluct

@NateEldredge: you mentioned OoO exec earlier.  Memory-reordering is a thing even on in-order CPUs.  They still have store buffers, and they can still scoreboard loads and do hit-under-miss and miss-under-miss in L1d cache to allow memory-level parallelism, all while starting execution of instructions in program order.  They stall if an instruction reads a load result that isn't ready yet, but there's a lot of ground between full OoO exec and fully unbuffered in-order where execution can't proceed until a store commits to coherent cache or a load takes a value.

@PeterCordes: From some simple tests, it appears you're right; compilers prefer to spill rather than move the relaxed load past a loop.  But in principle, since the requirement is that stores should be visible to loads, that means you musn't reorder a store after an indefinite loop (like the progress bar) nor reorder a load before such a loop.  The reverse (reordering a store before a loop, or a load after, as in this case) only makes the visibility "delay" shorter; it can even make it negative!
